# Adding data to arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

I had an idea for a way to bypass the hard limit on spaces for a normal array in Java. Would this work?

```
public class Array{
  private int[] group;

  public void addNums(int[] nums) {
    int[] list = new int[group.length + nums.length];
    for (int a = 0; a < group.length; a++)
      list[a] = group[a];
    for (int a = group.length; a < nums.length; a++)
      list[a] = nums[a - group.length];
    group = list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Take an `ArrayList` instead

Comment: `ArrayList` works the same way

Comment: Please follow the java [Naming Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) as it makes reading Java for others easier. e.g. a class should alwas start with a Capitalcased letter and a variable should always start with a lowercase letter. For the rest CamelCasing is used.

Comment: consider you should change second loop condition to `list.length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I commend you for trying to create your own `ArrayList` as you said you are a beginner to java.

You are really close there's just a small issue with your second for loop:

```
public void addNums(int[] nums) {
    int[] list = new int[group.length + nums.length];
    for (int a = 0; a < group.length; a++)
        list[a] = group[a];

    for (int a = group.length; a < list.length; a++)
        list[a] = nums[a -group.length];
    group = list;
}
```

You want it to loop to the end of your new `list`rather than `nums` because we want to use `a` to specify the position in the array the element is going.

Also, this might be a little offtopic but your solution there doesn't seem to be anywhere within your `Array` class to be able to specify what is within the `group[]`. So consider adding some getters and setters for testing:

```
public class Array {

    private int[] group;

    public int[] getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(int[] group) {

        this.group = group;
    }
```

And then when you are testing your `addNums()` method you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Array m = new Array();

    int[] startArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
    m.setGroup(startArray);

    int[] endArray = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    m.addNums(endArray);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getGroup()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations for using getter and setter methods, I do realize that there is no place that sets the `group[]`, but for the sake of keeping the code short, I neglected to include how it gets set.

Comment: Completely understandable @PeregrineLennert hope I helped

Comment: You did indeed help!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work, but you shouldn't re-invent the wheel. `ArrayList. addAll()` does this for you (one difference, there is no `ArrayList<int>`, only `ArrayList<Integer>`, but you'll hardly notice the difference).

So, I'd recommend to use `ArrayList` or `Vector` or some other `List` implementation.

Comment: Thank you for recommending ArrayLists, the only thing is I was trying to avoid using ArrayLists, as I am a beginner at Java.

Comment: Especially when you're a beginner at Java, you shouldn't avoid the standard Java solutions. So, your Array class might at best become an academic exercise, but for real-world programming, use ArrayLists.

Comment: Using `Vector` in 2017 is a very doubtful idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `int[]` instead `List<Integer>`, you can use `System.arraycopy()` method.

```
public void addNums(int[] nums) {
    int[] newGroup = new int[this.group.length + nums.length];

    // copy elements from group array to newGroup array
    System.arraycopy(group, 0, newGroup, 0, group.length);

    // copy elements from nums array to newGroup array
    System.arraycopy(nums, 0, newGroup, this.group.length, nums.length);

    this.group = newGroup;
}
```